# Why is my NAS intercepting external requests?

Tags: networking, routing, lan, nas

I've trying to host a webpage on my local computer. I've got a NAS on my LAN at 192.168.0.8, and my PC is on 192.168.0.2. My router is set up to direct all external requests to 192.168.0.2. However, whenever I visit mysite.com, I see the login page for my NAS, not the page on my PC.

Why might this be happening? How do I fix it?

Comment: Are you trying to access mysite.com from inside or outside your local network?

Comment: @DavidPostill from outside - the goal is to be able to access stuff on my home computer when travelling, so I'm trying to connect across the internet.